# How to insert data in custom coloumn in sales_creditmemo_item table from \Sales\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\Creditmemo\Save.php? magento 2

Tags: magento2, php, sales-order, sales, creditmemo

Basically I manually created custom column in my database named as **item_number** Now I want to insert data into this column from `app\code\company\Sales\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\Creditmemo\Save.php` and the purpose of this column is that it will store the item number of each item. As **sales_creditmemo_item** inserts data or stores data of each item of the order so I would like to add item Number of that item into **item_number** column in **sales_creditmemo_item** table.I have been referring to  `app\code\company\Sales\Model\Order\CreditMemo\Item.php`, `vendor\magento\module-sales\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\CreditmemoLoader.php` and `app\code\company\Sales\Api\Data\CreditMemoItemInterface.php` but it is confusing me to implement. But It would be really helpful for me to continue my learning about magento 2 backend concepts if anyone could point any suggestion or advice. Thanks and cheers

Comment: Basically you shoud not add columns to magento tables. To add custom data to creditmemo or creditmemo items please take a look at **\Magento\Sales\Api\Data\CreditmemoItemInterface**. As you can see it extends  **\Magento\Framework\Api\ExtensibleDataInterface**. So you should create your own table and use extension attributes. You can find more information here: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/extension_attributes/adding-attributes.html and https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/attributes.html

Comment: @MattiaKozianowski I created the table but I am kind of struggling in understanding the concept of extension attributes. If I am not wrong basically creating attribute extension is creating a module from scratch as here I would be referencing Magento\Sales\Api\Data\CreditmemoItemInterface. and this module will save and get data from database. Currently I haven't found any relevant example of creditmemo specifically but i am referring to https://store.fooman.co.nz/blog/an-introduction-to-extension-attributes.html still trying my best to understand the concept and will update if anything.

Comment: **etc\extension_attributes.xml** `<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Api/etc/extension_attributes.xsd">
    <extension_attributes for="Magento\Sales\Api\Data\CreditmemoItemInterface">
        <attribute code="sales_creditmemo_item_details" type="Company\CreditMemoItemDetails\Api\Data\CreditMemoItemDetailsAttributeInterface" />
    </extension_attributes>
</config>`

Comment: di.xml `<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Sales\Api\Data\CreditmemoItemRepositoryInterface">
        <plugin name="save_sales_creditmemo_item_details_attribute" type="Company\CreditMemoItemDetails\Model\Plugin\Save"/>
        <plugin name="get_sales_creditmemo_item_details_attribute" type="Company\CreditMemoItemDetails\Model\Plugin\Get"/>
    </type>
</config>`

Comment: after the above code was implemented i added my code in plugin Save.php in beforeSave( \Magento\Sales\Api\CreditMemoItemRepositoryInterface $subject,
        \Magento\Sales\Api\Data\CreditMemoItemInterface $entity) { //do something}but it is not working and doesn't give errors am i missing something? there are not much sources relevant to creditmemoitem on internet still trying my best to solve it and update if something

Comment: So for your extension_attribute you have to create also your custom DTO. To do this create your API interface: Vendor\Module\Api\Data\CreditmemoItemCountInterface. Create setter and getter methods. 
than create a model for the interface; Vendor\Module\Model\Data\CreditmemoItemCount that extends \Magento\Framework\Api\AbstractExtensibleObject and implements your interface.

Comment: Now before you save the creditmemo item you have to set your extension_attribute.
$creditmemoItemCount = $this->creditmemoIntemCount->create(); // Vendor\Module\Api\Data\CreditmemoItemCountInterfaceFactory
$creditmemoItemCount->setCount(3); //call your setter method

Now get extension attributes from creditmemoItem:

$extensionAttributes = $item->getExtensionAttributes(); // Magento\Sales\Api\Data\CreditmemoItemExtensionInterface
$extensionAttributes->setItemCount($creditmemoItemCount);
$item->setExtensionAttributes($extensionAttributes);

Comment: i did not tried this code but is should look like this.. Here you can find a little more information and examples: https://www.zynovo.com/blog/magento-2-extension-attributes/

https://www.interactiv4.com/e-commerce-en/extension-attributes-codehacks-i4/?lang=en

https://www.hellomagento2.com/extension-attributes/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106694/discussion-between-mattia-kozianowski-and-j-doe).

Comment: @MattiaKozianowski I created all the required files in the https://www.interactiv4.com/e-commerce-en/extension-attributes-codehacks-i4/?lang=en but my afterSave is not getting called as well as the data in my custom table is not getting saved though I am not agetting any errors or warnings thanks for your detailed explanation

Comment: <extension_attributes for="Magento\Sales\Api\Data\CreditmemoItemInterface">
       <attribute code="creditmemoitemdetail" type="Vendor\Sales\Api\Data\CreditmemoItemDetailInterface">
           <join reference_table="sales_creditmemo_item" reference_field="parent_id" join_on_field="entity_id">
               <field column="entity_id">entity_id</field>
               <field column="parent_id">parent_id</field>
               <field column="item_number">item_number</field>
  <field column="description">description</field>
           </join>
       </attribute>
   </extension_attributes>

Comment: di.xml=><type name="Vendor\Sales\Api\CreditmemoItemDetailRepositoryInterface">
       <plugin name="creditmemoitemdetail_plugin" type="Vendor\Sales\Plugin\Order\Creditmemo\CreditmemoItemDetailPlugin"/>
   </type>